# Keep minecraft book opened after click event

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating a tabletop RPG map and I'm using books to display the player's current status, but as soon as the player activates a click event on the book the book closes. This is a problem because the book displays plus and minus buttons next to a multi-digit number and I need the player to be able to freely click and adjust the value without the book closing.

Is there a way to prevent books from closing on activating a JSON click event?

Answer (score 1):

A written book is always closed upon clicking a JSON click event within the book unless it is a `change_page` click event, which will change the page of the book. The only way around this is to have the book on a lectern instead of in-inventory.

It is also impossible to update data dynamically while the book is being read. This is due to component resolution:

> When you use the JSON text components `score`, `selector`, and `nbt`, the system cannot render the value directly. Instead, these components must be resolved, meaning, converted into a text tag with the correct value. For example:
>
> This:
>
> ```
> {"score":{"name":"@p","objective":" text"}}
> ```
>
> must be converted into…
>
> ```
> {"text":"16"}
> ```
>
> <sup>with the correct value, of course</sup>
>
> This means that the component is only resolved once, so the value displayed will not dynamically update.

So you can have your book on a lectern instead, which will prevent the automatic closure, but be warned that updating info of the book while someone is reading it may cause them to be kicked out.

You may instead want to interest yourself in having the book display a single button "Adjust Status" that when clicked, closes the book and `/tellraw`s the buttons to change the status into the chat.

Comment: I keep getting kicked out with the book on a lectern too but that might be something else happening.  Do you know if the resolution also affects *hover* data?  A book has to have the page stay the same, but if I can put a score in a `hoverEvent` text that would be almost as good.

Comment: Update: even `hoverEvent`s need resolution and I still canʼt get a book to stay closed even in a lectern.

Comment: Hi @DanielH; I'm sorry but I quite doubt it is possible to change a book's contents while the user is reading it. AFAIK the only way to display dynamic components is with resolution; there is no such thing as displaying a dynamic value without resolving it. Thus it will be fixed and no dynamic updates.